# visual studioで作ったプログラムが起動できない。

Tags: windows, .net, visual-studio

友人に頼まれてVS2010でC#.netでプログラムを組みました。
私のPCでは問題なく動作するのですが、同じwindows7の友人のPCで起動すると

問題が発生したため、プログラムが正しく動作しなくなりました。プログラムは閉じられ、解決策がある場合はwindowsから通知されます。というメッセージが現れます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どこにどのようにすれば正常動作させることができるか思い当たる方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？
友人への受け渡しにレンタルサーバにexeファイルを圧縮したzipファイルをアップロードしてそれをダウンロードする形で渡したのですが、そういった渡し方が何かのセキュリティに引っかかったのではないかとも考えています。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: お互いのPCにインストールされている.NET Frameworkのバージョンは調べましたか？作成したプログラムのtarget Frameworkも確認して下さい。

Comment: buildする時の.net frameworkのversionを下げてみるのはどうでしょう？プロジェクトのプロパティから設定を変えられるハズです。
Windows7はデフォルトでは3.5辺りが入ってたと思います。まずは3.5でbuildしなおして、提供してみる。※もちろん3.5でbuildできない作りであれば、この方法は使えません。

Answer (score 2):

【よくある可能性】

- 必要なライブラリ(DLL)が不足しているか、バージョンが異なる。
- .NET Frameworkのバージョンが古い、または、破損している。
- 必要なアクセス権限が不足している。ファイルを書き込みできない等。
- セキュリティソフトの影響を受けている。

【解決策】
　**参照しているライブラリのバージョンに矛盾がないか確認する。**

```
hoge.exe --- piyo.dll ver 1.0.1.0
fuge.dll --- piyo.dll ver 1.0.0.9
```

このような構成になっている場合、piyo.dllのバージョン違いによる影響を受けることがあります。
fuge.dllがpiyo.dll ver 1.0.1.0を参照するように修正する必要があります。

**可能であれば、ログを確認してもらう**

.NET アプリケーションが不正終了した場合、**管理ツール→イベントビューア**の**Windowsログ→アプリケーション**にて例外を確認できます。

Answer (score 1):

プログラムのエラー処理がなされていない場合に表示されるダイアログです。
自分のPCで動作するのは偶然なだけですので、きちんとエラー処理を行いましょう。どのようなエラーが発生しているのかはプログラム自身、および作者のあなたにしかわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

一番ありそうな原因は、他の方の回答にあるようなライブラリや必要なファイルが無い、
といったものですが、ほかにも「そもそもプログラムにバグがある」可能性もあります。

たとえば

- あなたのパソコン固有のフォルダやファイルが無いと動かない仕組みではないか。
- 特定のアプリやデータが無いと動かない仕組みではないか。

といったあたりを確認されてみてはどうでしょうか？
（これをバグと呼ぶかどうかは微妙かもしれませんが、期待通りに動かない原因、
　という意味では広義のバグでしょう）

一番手っ取り早いのは、きちんとしたエラー処理を行い、どんなエラーが出ているか
具体的に突き止める手段をプログラムに付け加えることです。エラーが起きたら、
その内容やその時のデータをテキストファイルに出力するようなエラー処理を追加し、
改めてご友人のPCで動かしてもらう、というのが手っ取り早いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

あくまで可能性ですが、「プログラム中でDLLの動的読み込みを行っていて」「ロードするDLLが『他のコンピューターから取得されたファイル』とマークされている」場合はDLLの読み込みに失敗します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ファイルを圧縮せずに配布したり、ZIPファイルをエクスプローラーで解凍しているような場合はセキュリティフラグが立ちますのでご確認ください。

Answer (score 0):

みなさんありがとうございました。
エラー処理をしていないというのはその通りでちゃんとエラー処理をするのが本来なのですが、部分的に自分で作っていない部分もありすべてを理解して作り直すのが困難であったため、動かしたいPCにVSを入れてそちら側でビルドすることで動かしました。

皆さんありがとうございました。